# Centos my application is not working with php5.4 but 5.3 now i want to install 5.3 but can not

Tags: php, centos

**Here i have centos 5.5
i have php5.4 which is not compitable with my application so i did.**

```
yum remove php php-*
```

now back if i want to reinstall php5.3 when i do the

```
yum search php53 | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep php
```

it list me the php5.3 but when i want install it by:

```
yum install php53
```

it updates me and asks me to install php54 which i don't want any hint or quid will be
your kindness
**here i need to install php5.3 on centos5.5**
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to update yum

```
yum remove php php-*
```

Then remove php

```
yum remove php php-*
```

Also httpd

```
yum remove httpd
```

Reinstall httpd

```
yum install httpd
```

reinstall all php packages required

```
yum install php53u-pear php53u php53u-cli php53u-common php53u-devel php53u-gd php53u-mbstring php53u-mcrypt php53u-mysql php53u-pdo php53u-soap php53u-xml php53u-xmlrpc php53u-bcmath php53u-pecl-apc php53u-pecl-memcache php53u-snmp
```

finally fix APC

```
yum remove php53u-pecl-apc
yum update php53u-pecl-apc --enablerepo=ius-testing
```

:)

Comment: id did remove php php-* and httpd and reinstall but when it comes to php the (No package phpxxxx available)

Comment: post your terminal output.

Comment: No package php53u-pear available.